# WebSocket connection not working in React Native useEffect with Socket.IO

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to establish a WebSocket connection in a React component using Socket.IO within a useEffect hook. However, the connection doesn't seem to work, and I'm unable to figure out why. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = 'TOKEN';
    const headers = {
      ['Authorization']: 'bearer ' + token,
    };

    const socket = io('URL', {
      auth: {
        ['Authorization']: 'bearer ' + token,
      },
      timeout: 10000,
      autoConnect: true,
      transports: ['websocket'],
      extraHeaders: headers,
    });

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('WebSocket client connected');
    });

    socket.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
      console.log('WebSocket client disconnected:', reason);
    });

    socket.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log('WebSocket message:', data);
    });

    socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket connect error:', error);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    // JSX for your component
  );
}
```

This is the current output:
[image]

It works perfectly fine when trying to connect with HTTP auth headers using Insomnia REST-Client:
[image]

Any suggestions to why the native client cannot connect?

Comment: try logging `error.message`

Comment: only gives me 'websocket error'. No details unfortunatley.

Comment: Any news on this?